# structure and file handling in c

Tags: c

im reading from a file into an array of structure and then prints out question by question !

it looks like this in the file !

```
1: När kom potatisen till Europa?;A:1300-talet;B:1500-talet;C:900-talet;D:1700-talet;B
D

2: I vilken enhet mats elektrisk spänning ?;A:Ampere;B:Volt;C:Joule;D:Watt
B

3: Från vilket land har vi fått lego?;A:Tyskland;B:Australien;C:Japan;D:Danmark
D
```

And this is my code !

```c
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct quiz
{
    char questions[50];
    char* alt[4];
    char correctanswer[1];
};

int main() {

    struct quiz all_ques[50];
    int i = 0;

    char answer;
    FILE *haidar;
    haidar = fopen("gameee.txt", "r");
    char str[500];
    char *ptr;

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), haidar))               // read 500 characters
    {

        ptr = strtok(str, ";");  // split our findings around the " ;"

        if (ptr == NULL) {
        }    
        else {
            strcpy(all_ques[i].questions, ptr); // store the question
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); // and keep splitting
        if (ptr == NULL) {
        }
        else {
            all_ques[i].alt[0] = malloc(10);
            strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[0], ptr);// store the first option
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); // and keep splitting
        if (ptr == NULL) {
        }
        else{
            all_ques[i].alt[1] = malloc(10);
            strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[1], ptr); // store the second option
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); // and keep splitting
        if (ptr == NULL) {       
        }    
        else {
            all_ques[i].alt[2] = malloc(10);
            strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[2], ptr);    // store the third option
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); // and keep splitting
        if (ptr == NULL) {
        }    
        else {
            all_ques[i].alt[3] = malloc(10);
            strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[3], ptr);    // store the fourth option
        }

        while (fgets(str, 500, haidar)== NULL); {
             printf("error\n");    
        }

        if (str == NULL) {    
            printf("error\n");
        }    
        else{
            strcpy(all_ques[i].correctanswer, str); // store the correct answer
            fgets(str, sizeof(str), haidar); // read one line (and throw it away)    
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", all_ques[0].questions, all_ques[0].alt[0], all_ques[0].alt[1], all_ques[0].alt[2], all_ques[0].alt[3],ptr);


    answer = (getch());    

    if  (answer == all_ques[0].correctanswer[0]) {    
        printf("right\n");
    }
    else    
        printf("wrong\n");        
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", all_ques[1].questions, all_ques[1].alt[0], all_ques[1].alt[1], all_ques[1].alt[2], all_ques[1].alt[3], ptr);

    answer = (getch());  
    if  (answer == all_ques[1].correctanswer[0]) {
        printf("right\n");
    }
    else
        printf("wrong\n");
}
```

I want to print out the question and then the alternatives  where the user will choose from, and so on. but when i run it in vs 2013 i get this error

```
Debug assertion failed!
line 57
expression (str!=NULL)
```

But there is no line 57!! please help

Comment: That line is that of the code...

Comment: sorry! i dont understand @SouravGhosh

Comment: Don't check the line number in your input file. Check that line in your code.

Comment: Line 57 as I read it occurs in between one of these:         `if(ptr == NULL){


        }`
Your compiler is telling you there is an error at line 57 in your code, not that you have an error with a variable "line 57" or on line 57 of your input file or anything strange like that :).

Comment: ok! i tried to read the code line by line several times but i can found the error!

Comment: You really violate the *DRY* principle, maybe you should start there. Also `malloc(10)` seems incorrect, because 1. The string might be larger (use `strdup()` or `strlen()` to determine how much to `malloc()`). 2. If it's always 10 bytes, it's not necessary to do that because it would introduce the risk of memory leaks.

Comment: Your question at the moment is quite hard to answer because it requires a lot of time to read and understand what you're trying to do. It may be worth trying to recreate this problem in the shortest possible program so that we can help you debug it better. You can find more information on how to better your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Samidamaru: This is an assertion. The compiler is not involved in running the program.

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which might encounter an error. e.g. all/most file-functions. You apparently pass a null-pointer where it is not expected (but caught by a foreseeing programmer)..

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to create a quiz game where i have a file with questions , alternatives and right answer.  Question with answers should be stored together in the form of a struct variable. The program dealt with a struct variable (with a question and answer) as elements of a vector. At the same time, these data shall be stored on file. A line for each question + answer, semi-colon separated:

Comment: . Since I do not know how many questions that file (with the permanently stored list) contains, I must first determine the number of lines in the file. You can then dynamically allocate memory to the vector and read the questions from the file. The program needs then manage the list as a pointer to the struct variable data type. The words read words from the file as one of the first measures .

Comment: @Olaf you are quite right. Would edit but SO won't let me. My wording should be "Your program at run is telling you an assertion failed at line 57 of your code" or words to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

The code has several serious problems :

- line 64 delete `;`, you have an infinite loop here!
- it is not useful to compare `str` against `NULL` (this is always false!), this seems to cause your problem at runtime (my compiler complains at compile-time)
- the two `printf` line 78 and 88 have too much arguments (reconsider the format...).

After correcting, it seems to work (at least I was able to answer two questions)...